# Display a <select> with information from an API in?

Tags: javascript, html, json, api

I'm trying to figure out how to display information from an API in a select.

The user has to select a start station with the  itself linked to the api. But I can't create option, having the names of each station, in my select.

Can you help me understand my mistake?

```html
<section class="container">
  <div class="item">
  <p>list</p>
  <select id="subwaystation"> 
  </select>
```

```js
var apiStations = "https://api-ratp.pierre-grimaud.fr/v4/stations/metros/8";

function req1() {
fetch(apiStations, {
  method: "get"
})
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(data => {
   let allstations= data.result.stations;
    for(var i = 0; i < allstations.length; i++) {
      html += "<option value=" + key  + ">" +obj[key] + "</option>"
  }
  document.getElementById("subwaystation").innerHTML = html;
  })
}
req1();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code contains some simple errors which you should be able to see in your browser's Console, which would give you clues about why it's not working.

First you'd see that `html` is not defined before you try to append to it. You can't append to something which doesn't exist.

if you fix that then you'd see that `key` and then `obj` are also not defined. It's not clear where you expected those to come from or what you think they would contain. I wonder if you simply copied and pasted some code you found without stopping to examine it properly or consider whether it fits with the context you pasted it into.

You can fix these issues very straightforwardly by

1. declaring `html` as an empty string before your loop starts, so the `+=` has something to append to

2. When creating the `<option`, referring to the station object at the current index (`i`) of the loop and then the specific properties found in that object (`slug` and `name`, as shown in the raw JSON), instead of using `key` and `obj` which do not come from anywhere else in your code.

Demo:

```js
var apiStations = "https://api-ratp.pierre-grimaud.fr/v4/stations/metros/8";

function req1() {
  fetch(apiStations, {
      method: "get"
    })
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => {
      let allstations = data.result.stations;
      let html = '';
      for (var i = 0; i < allstations.length; i++) {
        html += "<option value=" + allstations[i].slug + ">" + allstations[i].name + "</option>"
      }
      document.getElementById("subwaystation").innerHTML = html;
    })
}
req1();
```

```html
<select id="subwaystation">
</select>
```

Comment: Thank you, i was trying so much things and i was not so far from the right answer.I would need to be put on voice if you don't mind. I can display the api messages but how do I get the message to change when I choose another station :
https://api-ratp.pierre-grimaud.fr/v4/schedules/metros/8/balard/A
as each message will be different depending on the station selected. I can't think of a solution where when I select my station, the right message is displayed (in this case, Balard).